# Push subscription p256dh key is related to public VAPID application server key anyhow?

Tags: javascript, encryption, push-notification

I'm building service which allows users to use web push notifications on their pages. I have a following problem: when someone visits page where my script (and service worker) is working I can check if he is already subscribed to receiving web push notifications:

```
const swRegistration = await navigator.serviceWorker.ready;
const pushSubscription = await swRegistration.pushManager.getSubscription();
```

From pushSubscription I can retrieve browser public key p256dh and auth secret as described here https://web.dev/push-notifications-web-push-protocol/#inputs. I am already sending my public VAPID server application key to client in form of json web token. I'd need and I'd like to check if above existing retrieved pushSubscription was obtained using my public VAPID key - and not some foreign key. Is it possible to achieve in anyway, are those key related to each other in any way? I need that to check if visitor has subscribed with my service and therefore if sending subscription authenticating with my private VAPID key will work.